# Which has higher growth rate between log(n!) and log(n)?

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity

I have just started learning and practicing algorithms and I read in a book that log(n!) has a faster growth rate than log(n).

```
log(n!) = log((n)*(n-1)*.....(1))  
log(n!) = log(n)+log(n-1)+....+log(1)  <--- (i)

taking the worst case from (i), which is log(n)
therefore, log(n) should have same growth rate as log(n!)
```

Then how is it that log(n!) is better than log(n)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lets try a different approach

**1.**

### `n! = n*(n-1)*(n-2)*...*1` **<** `n*n*n.....*n`

```
n! < n^n
log(n!) < log(n^n)
log(n!) < nlogn
** log(n!) = O(nlogn)
```

---

**2.**

```
n! = 
n*(n-1)*(n-2)*....*n/2*(n/2-1)*...*1 > (n/2)*(n/2)*(n/2)*...*(n/2)
                                       ---------------------------
                                                  n/2 times
```

This is true because:

```
n > n/2
n-1 > n/2
n-2 > n/2
.
.
n/2 == n/2
```

So now we know: `log(n!) > log((n/2)^(n/2)`

```
log(n!) > n/2*log(n/2)
*** log(n!) = Ω(nlogn)
```

From `**` and `***` we get:
`log(n!) = θ(nlogn)`

Hence `log(n) = O(log(n!))`